# Make imgur link have .png or .jpg in the end of the url with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, url, imgur

I have a node JS application that gets images from reddit.com/r/wallpaper.

You make a request on the html page and it gets a random image and displays it on the `<img>`.

Problem is sometimes you get imgur urls like `http://imgur.com/a/Vtav5` which cannot be displayed on the `<img>`, but urls like `http://i.imgur.com/vjUeUVj.jpg` can be displayed, on Node.js how can i get the url to become a direct image url? Heres my currently working code.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    r.getSubreddit(subreddit).getRandomSubmission().then(function(post){

        if(post.url.includes(".jpg") || post.url.includes(".png")){
            currentUrl = post.url;
            console.log(currentUrl);
            res.send(currentUrl);
            res.end();

        } else{
            console.log("Not a direct image URL");
            console.log(post.url);
        }

        });
    console.log("Got request");
    //res.end();


})
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not available via their API, best you can do is scrape it and hopefully the number of links you need to scrape won't be too large.

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('http://imgur.com/a/Vtav5', '.post-images .post-image', [{
  url: 'a@href'
}])(function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
})
```

Output:

```
[ { url: 'http://i.imgur.com/vjUeUVj.jpg' } ]
```

Comment: Ijust encountered this annoying problem, I think you cant change vairables while the server is up and listening.

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox what do you mean?

Comment: When you run the server I dont think any variables can be changed, the url is a variable and needs to be changed constantly to a new vairable

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox that's just an example. you can wrap it up inside a function and use it.

as for the xpath, it will stay the same as long as imgur doesn't change their html structure.