# Get image-urls from imgur link in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, x-ray

I need to get the image urls from imgur post urls.

The urls of the posts looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPmGJ.jpg

But the image urls look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyVaJ.jpg

I tryed it with the web-scraping library x-ray js but for some reason it doesn't work. For some reason I just get an empty array.

My code (I use Firebase Cloud Functions):

```
    var Xray = require('x-ray');

    exports.getImgurLink = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        var xray = Xray();
    
        xray('https://imgur.com/a/1QEKZ2f', '.image-placeholder')(function (err, res) {
            console.log("res: "+res);
        })
    });
```

I have the idea with the xray from this Post: [Make imgur link have .png or .jpg in the end of the url with nodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404064/make-imgur-link-have-png-or-jpg-in-the-end-of-the-url-with-nodejs) but it is already older so I am not sure if it still works.

Can someone show me another method to get image urls from imgur or how to fix my xray code?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use puppeteer to do that. With your example links:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

exports.getImgurLink = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    let url = "https://imgur.com/gallery/kgfDi"

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)

    const el = await page.$x('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/img')

    el.forEach(async function(element){
        const src = await element.getProperty('src')
        const scrText = await src.jsonValue()

        console.log({ scrText })
    })
});
```